# I can not connect to the container in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Getting the IP address of the minicube

```
minikube ip

192.168.49.2
```

This is the content of the pod.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: short-app
  labels:
    component: frontend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "500m"
```

This is the content of the service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: short-app-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31202
  selector:
    component: frontend
```

I have completed kubectl apply pod.yaml and kubectl apply service.yaml

When trying to go to GET http://192.168.49.2:31202/ , I get a mistake like in screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQG5l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting service endpoints: `kubectl get endpoints`.

If the service has no endpoints, it means that it's not correctly selecting any pods.

Also, try to `minikube ssh`, and `curl localhost:<node_port>`. you should see nginx response in the curl result.